How to import these files with lists
I exported some lists without setting an export format. Usually I could read anything using Readlist. However, this does not seem to work. Here is a self-contained example:
data = {{{0.1`, 0.001`}, {9.988873221143896`*^46}}, {{0.1`, 
 0.001584893192461114`}, {6.230456240313458`*^46}}};
Export["test.dat", data];
data2 = Import["test.dat"];

data2 results in a list of strings. I also tried setting an import format "Table" or "List" with no luck. Please note that the data was already exported in the files and so the export format cannot be changed now, unless I re-process the output files somehow.

Try the following workaround:
data = {{{0.1`, 0.001`}, {9.988873221143896`*^46}}, {{0.1`, 
     0.001584893192461114`}, {6.230456240313458`*^46}}};

Export["C:/test.dat", FullForm@data, "String"];

imported = First@ReadList["C:/test.dat"]

imported == data


True

EDIT
If data is already in the format that it is, then try:
imported = 
 ReadList["C:/test.dat", "String"] // 
    Map[StringReplace["\t" -> ","]] // 
   Map[StringJoin["{", #, "}"] &] // Map[ToExpression]


I get: Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in {0.1,0.001} {9.98887*10^46} cannot be combined.

I have updated. Please check now.

Great, now works!

You can use .mx format, which is fully supported by Wolfram language.
data = {{{0.1`, 0.001`}, {9.988873221143896`*^46}}, {{0.1`, 
     0.001584893192461114`}, {6.230456240313458`*^46}}};
Export["test.mx", data];
data2 = Import["test.mx"];
data == data2
(*True*)

